# Як правильно, "У лузі" чи "НА лузі"?

Tags: прийменники

Як правильно, "У лузі" чи "НА лузі"? Який прийменник тут коректно ставити?

Comment: А про що йде мова? https://goroh.pp.ua/Тлумачення/лузі

Comment: Should be closed in the current state, not enough details.

Answer (score 2):

Якщо [*луг* у значенні «лука»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)), то вживається і так, і так:

> Далій за чагарниками розіслався оксамитом широкий зелений луг; на лузі де-не-где невеличкі озерця, останки весняної води блищать мов краплі живого срібла. //  Олександр Кониський, «Юрій Горовенко. Хроніка з смутного часу», 1883.
>
> Товстий бик і скороногий олінь паслися разом у лузі. // Маркіян Шашкевич, «Байки», 1836.

Також, як правильно [зазначає Andriy Ivanchenko](/q/6156#comment10209_6156), є ще [*луг* у хімічному значенні](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8_(%D1%85%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%8F)) і [*луза*](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=48515&page=1529).